# Persistent disk not visible on Google Cloud instance

Tags: google-compute-engine

I am running an instance on google cloud and I have attached a spare 500gb disk through the console. On the machine I can only see

```
$ df -aTh
Filesystem                                             Type      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
rootfs                                                 rootfs    9.8G  1.3G  8.0G  14% /
sysfs                                                  sysfs        0     0     0    - /sys
proc                                                   proc         0     0     0    - /proc
udev                                                   devtmpfs   10M     0   10M   0% /dev
devpts                                                 devpts       0     0     0    - /dev/pts
tmpfs                                                  tmpfs     372M  152K  372M   1% /run
/dev/disk/by-uuid/7ad09482-d361-4685-8581-c8a3a12e8103 ext4      9.8G  1.3G  8.0G  14% /
tmpfs                                                  tmpfs     5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
tmpfs                                                  tmpfs     743M     0  743M   0% /run/shm
```

I have tried to remove and reattach the disk from the console but I see nothing coming up on the machine. Any clues?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Given that `df` only shows you *mounted* filesystems, and you haven't mentioned anything about mounting your new block device, you probably want to `cat /proc/partitions` instead, to find your new disk.

Comment: `lsblk` is also quite handy. I believe it just presents the contents of `/proc/partitions` in a slightly nicer fashion.

Comment: Managed to mount it running, mkdir /media/500gb; sudo /usr/share/google/safe_format_and_mount /dev/sdb /media/500gb

Comment: @EEAA: you kids and your new-fangled tools...